# Removing data from Firebase Realtime Database removes all the data in the parent node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase and am writing code to delete data from Realtime Database.
What I am trying to do is to remove a saved post from a user's bookmarks section when the button is clicked, and here is the key part of the code:

```
let user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
var ref1=firebase.database().ref('saved/'+user.uid+'/posts/').orderByChild('postnum').equalTo(j); //j is the postnum of the post to be deleted
ref1.once('value',function(snapshot){
    snapshot.ref.remove();
});
```

Instead of removing the info about the specific post, the code would clear all the posts that the user previously saved. (i.e. this would clear all data from 'saved/user.uid/posts/' directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So the `snapshot` variable contains a list of result. And `snapshot.ref` refers to the location where you ran the query. So when you do `snapshot.ref.delete()`, you're deleting the entire location where you ran the query, not just the results.

To delete the results, loop over the children of snapshot, and delete them one by one:

```
let user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
var ref1=firebase.database().ref('saved/'+user.uid+'/posts/').orderByChild('postnum').equalTo(j); //j is the postnum of the post to be deleted
ref1.once('value',function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.remove();
  });
});
```

You can also delete them in one go after the loop with a multi-location update:

```
let user=firebase.auth().currentUser;
var ref1=firebase.database().ref('saved/'+user.uid+'/posts/').orderByChild('postnum').equalTo(j); //j is the postnum of the post to be deleted
ref1.once('value',function(snapshot){
  let updates = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    updates[child.key] = null;
  });
  ref1.update(updates);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I applied the first code and it worked perfectly. :)